# Android: Inflating Linear Views within ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I have a class that gets items from a database and then places them into a layout and inflates. This loops through each item in the database inflating a new layout for each item. This eventually extends past the viewport and will need a scroll bar which I assume will be a ScrollView. I've tried many different ways and can't get it to scroll through the entire content. Please advise.

Java:

```
View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.myviews, null);

TextView tvQuote = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.lblQuote);
//Set an id to know which quote is in use
tvQuote.setId(i);
TextView tvShared = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.lblShared);
TextView tvSaid = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.lblSaid);

//Change name dynamically
tvQuote.setText((strQuote).toString());
tvShared.setText(("Shared by: " + strFName + " " + strLInitial).toString());
tvSaid.setText(("Said by: " + strFNameSaid + " " + strLInitialSaid).toString());
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/myMainLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="Quoter" 
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 
        android:textSize="16px" 
        android:padding="5px" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

myviews.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
          <TextView
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1pt"
            android:background="#6F7285"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>     
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What would be the best solution to scroll through all of these inflated layouts?

Comment: I actually found that adding the ScrollView to the main.xml was the fix. Thanks for all your help though guys. I'd still like to know if I am doing this wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that adding the ScrollView to the main.xml was the fix. Thanks for all your help though guys. I'd still like to know if I am doing this wrong though.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're doing too much work.  If your data is in a SQLite database then you can use a SimpleCursorAdapter with your ListView which will do the heavy lifting for you:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // The my_list_activity layout is the container for each
        // item in the list.
        setContentView(R.layout.my_list_activity);

        // Create a database cursor for the data you want to query.
        // Assumes your data is accessible via a ContentProvider.

        // Note: db.CONTENT_URI is whatever URI your ContentProvider uses,
        // and db.COL1 etc are constants that would name the columns you want.
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(db.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { db._ID, db.COL1, db.COL2, db.COL3 },
            null, null, null);

        // Bind the value in db.COL1 to the resource with the id text1, and so
        // on for the other two columns.
        //
        // Assumes that the view has TextViews with IDs text1, text2, and text3.
        String[] from= new String[] { db.COL1, db.COL2, db.COL3 };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 };

        // Create the adapter, bound to the cursor, layout, and the mapping from
        // column name to TextView ID.
        //
        // Assumes a layout called my_list_activity_item exists, with at least
        // 3 views called text1, text2, and text3.
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.my_list_activity_item, cursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

If your data is not in an SQLite database then look at the other classes that derive from android.widget.BaseAdapter to see if one of them suits you.

Comment: If you haven't used a ListView before, you may want to watch this: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html They're quite a bit different conceptually from the approach in your question.

Comment: My data is in a MS SQL database on a web server.

Comment: You can still use a Content Provider as a proxy for the web service.  This material from O'Reilly covers that in some detail -- http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/ch13.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many linearlayouts in your myviews.xml. This should do the trick for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblQuote" 
            android:text="text"
            />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblQuote" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="text"
            /> 
        <TextView
            android:text="text "
            android:background="#6F7285"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblShared" 
            />     
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I added some placeholder text so you can see it. Remove whatever you don't need.

Comment: I get a force close when attempting this.

Comment: The force close cannot be due to the xml. What does the logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick answer is that you need a `ScrollView` around all of those `LinearLayout`s so you can actually scroll (your first LinearLayout has height=wrap_content). The long version is that you're probably doing it wrong and you should be using a `ListView` and an `Adapter` instead.

Comment: The content is really just text, non selectable, non-intractable. Just text. Is the ListView still the correct way to go about doing this? If so what is the benefit?

Comment: No problem, it's just a presentation standard. Scalability is a big one. Your database can grow without you having to recode everything.